# MongoDB MQL, split list in two and get only unique values

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mql

I'm having a books collection in MongoDB.

Each has a categories list up to 2 entries, example :

```
categories: [
   'Thriller'
]
```

or

```
categories: [
   'Adventure',
   'Action'
]
```

Using MongoDB MQL I need to get two categories lists filtered to project :

- first list with uniques first values of categories
- second list with uniques second values of categories

I can only use $group, $addToSet and $arrayElemAt (no $unwind).

Here where I am and I can't find the way to do it :

```
collection.aggregate(
    [
        {"$group":
            {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "categories1" : { "$addToSet": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$categories", 0 ] } },
                "categories2" : { "$addToSet": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$categories", 1 ] } }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Example of entry in books collection :

```
{
    _id: 2,
    title: 'HARRY POTTER A L'ECOLE DES SORCIERS - ILLUSTRE PAR MINALIMA',
    isbn: '2075145938',
    pageCount: 368,
    publishedDate: ISODate('2020-10-22T08:00:00.000Z'),
    shortDescription: 'Découvrez ou redécouvrez le texte intégral...',
    status: 'PUBLISH',
    authors: [
        'J.K. Rowling',
        'Minalima'
    ],
    categories: [
        'Youth',
        'Adventure'
    ]
}
```

Expected output :

```
{
    categories1 : [
        'Youth',
        'Thriller',
        'Newspaper'],
    categories2 : [
        'Adventure',
        'Newspaper',
        'Essai'],

}
```

categories1 include only unique values from categories with 0 index (first value) and categories2 include only unique values from categories but this time in second position (index 1).

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a full sample json document and expected output instead of the current fragmented fields?

Comment: Wrt _"second list with uniques second values of categories"_ - so what happens for the book with `categories: [ 'Thriller' ]` ? Should 'Thriller' appear in both lists (as unique 2nd) or only in the first, if not book has it as a second category?

Comment: I edited the question.
@aneroid 'Thriller' must appears in the categories1 list, but if any book has 'Thriller' has a second category this value will also be present into categories2 list, but for both lists only one time (unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is *almost correct*. You only need to change the `_id` for `$group`. Since you want the unique lists across *all books*, don't group on `$_id` - that would treat each object/book individually. Use `null` to group across all books in the collection:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {"$group":
            {
                "_id": null,  // this is the only line I changed
                "categories1" : { "$addToSet": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$categories", 0 ] } },
                "categories2" : { "$addToSet": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$categories", 1 ] } }
            }
        },
        { "$project": { "_id": 0 } }
    ]
)
```

And since you don't want `_id: null` in the result, I've added a second stage `$project` in the pipeline.

Btw, if you're putting that aggregation pipeline directly in Python, change the `"_id": null` to  `"_id": None`

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kNt74dBIpQ2)

example data:

```js
[
  {
    title: "book one title",
    categories: [ "Thriller" ]
  },
  {
    title: "book TWO title",
    categories: [ "Adventure", "Action" ]
  },
  {
    title: "book 3 title",
    categories: [ "Action", "Musical", "Animated" ]
  },
  {
    title: "fourth book",
    categories: [ "Thriller", "Musical" ] // both of these are duplicate categories
  }
]
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "categories1": [ "Thriller", "Adventure", "Action" ],
    "categories2": [ "Musical", "Action" ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @aneroid
I'm using it with pymongo so I had this error :
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Changed it for "_id": None but now : NameError: name '_id' is not defined

Comment: @Dimitri This error `NameError: name '_id' is not defined` cannot occur since _id is a string. _Unless it's not._ Make sure you quote it and not use it like a variable. Do this: `{ "$group: { "_id": None, ... }`. (I think you forgot the quotes and did `{ "$group: { _id: None, ... }` which won't work since `_id` is not a variable or a defined name in the code).

Comment: got this error : <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x7f145181f7c0> with the None value

Comment: :-) That's not an error. When you execute an aggregate pipeline, or anything that can return multiple documents, you usually get a [_`Cursor`_](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) in PyMongo (and most other Mongo libraries for different languages). Which you need to iterate over to get all the results. Put `return list(cursor)` to get the resulting documents, or an empty list of there are no results. (I use a `return [do_something(doc) for doc in cursor]` loop or list comprehension.)

Comment: Also, the [PyMongo tutorials](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document) and [`aggregate()` docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) will help.

Comment: just starting mongo :)
thank you so much @aneroid